# How to link dylib file in C++ builder project

Tags: c++, macos, c++builder, dylib, ftdi

I am using Embarcadero C++Builder 10.1 Berlin Update 2 on Windows 7 32-bit, connected to a MacBook running with macOS Sierra (v10.12.1).

I am trying to write a Mac OSX app that reads data from an FTDI device using D2XX method (FTDI API).

I include `FTD2xx.h` in my code, and it compiles successfully.  But it fails on the link stage:

> [FIXME Error] Error: Unresolved external '_FT_CreateDeviceInfoList' referenced from D:\PROJECT_SRC\OSX32\DEBUG\DEVICEQUERY.O

I should link to `libftd2xx.dylib` but I don't know how.

I tried to add the dylib path to "Library paths" in the "Edit SDK" dialog, but that didn't work.

Any idea?

Comment: Do you have an associated `.a` or `.o` file for the dylib?  Have you added the `.a`/`.o`file to your project?

Comment: Hi Remy, Thanks for your help.I've tried to add static lib "libftd2xx.a" to my project but I got the error: 'LIBFTD2XX.A' lists no symbols in its dictionary. It seems that C++ Builder doesn't accept macOS format.

Answer (score 0):

if you haven't included .h before your first compilation, you probably need to clean directory with object files, /debug folder, delete existing builds and then try to rebuild and show what's happening, ofc if you didnt try this before, or I've read badly.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I do include the header file (.h) or it fails on compiling stage. I tried your comment to delete existing builds folder but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I added dylib file directly to C++ Builder project by selecting the filter to "All files" and it works now!